# Integrating log4cxx and kafka

Tags: logging

What is the best way to push logs from a C++ server using log4cxx for logging to a kafka cluster? Is there any compatible log4cxx appender or any proxy that I could deploy in the middle?

Answer (score 0):

Log4cxx comes with a syslog appender you can use to log either to the local syslog or a remote syslog. Combine that with [klogd](https://github.com/leandrosilva/klogd) and you should be able to feed anything that comes out of a Unix system into Kafka.

Details here: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/logging/site/trunk/docs/log4cxx/apidocs/classlog4cxx_1_1net_1_1_syslog_appender.html